# Relative positioning in WPF xaml

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to position a control in the XAML definiton relative to another control?
for example if I want to place a control exactly in the middle of another wider control.
and if so - how?

Comment: For starters, have you tried using HorizontalAlignment="Center" for the inner control?

Comment: Centering the control is just an example. I'm looking for something more general :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to center the controls you could wrap them in a grid:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="132"   Width="229" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Width="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Other positioning can be accomplished by other panels like StackPanel etc. Grid beeing the most flexible choice.

Edit: updated with grid and columns for controlling position:

```
<Grid Height="50" Width="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" />
    <Button Content="Button"  Grid.Column="2"   />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok, but centering the control was just an example. what if I want the one control to start 20 units after the other control?

Comment: I just typed in some random numbers. You should be able to get the desired positioning playing around with Widths, Heights Column& Rowspans.

Comment: So it's all done through the panels? Can't controls use eachothers properties like width or height?

Comment: Controlling the positions of child elements is the purpose of the panels. Actually pretty nice OO if you ask me.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx