# How to make wpf application window resize properly?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created the home screen of fixed size for some application as shown in code below. The problem is that when I change the size of the window, or if I run it with maximized window, everything gets messed up and overlapped.

```
<Window x:Class="Mastersolution.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Left="0" Top="0">


    <Grid Background = "Cyan" >



        <TextBox Name="ButtonDescription" Text="" Margin="329,438,319,163" />



        <!-- import button -->
        <Button Name ="Btn_Import" Margin="120,260,757,330"  Click="Btn_Import_Click" MouseEnter="import_desc" MouseLeave="desc_clear" >
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="bg">
                        <Image Name ="import_image" Source="/Images/Import.png"/>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!-- hover effect -->
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                            <!-- press effect -->
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>

            <Button.Style>
                <!-- initially disabled-->
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>

            <!-- fade effect while disabled-->
            <Button.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.OpacityMask>

        </Button>

        <Label Name ="ImportLabel" Content="IMPORT" Margin="133,367,757,287" FontSize="20"/>


        <!-- studio button -->
        <Button Name ="Studio" Margin="310,251,535,330" Click="Studio_Click" MouseEnter="studio_desc" MouseLeave="desc_clear">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="bg">
                        <Image Source="/Images/Studio.png"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>

            <Button.Style>
                <!-- initially disabled-->
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>

            <!-- fade effect while disabled-->
            <Button.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.OpacityMask>

        </Button>

        <Label Name ="StudioLabel" Content="STUDIO" Margin="346,367,555,287" FontSize="20"/>

        <!-- animation button -->
        <Button Name ="Animation" Margin="556,260,338,330" Click="Animation_Click" MouseEnter="animation_desc" MouseLeave="desc_clear">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="bg">
                        <Image Source="/Images/Animation.jpg"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>

            <Button.Style>
                <!-- initially disabled-->
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>

            <!-- fade effect while disabled-->
            <Button.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.OpacityMask>

        </Button>

        <Label Name ="AnimationLabel" Content="ANIMATION" Margin="544,367,319,287" FontSize="20"/>

        <!-- record button -->
        <Button Name ="Record" Margin="758,251,88,330" Click="Record_Click" MouseEnter="record_desc" MouseLeave="desc_clear">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="bg">
                        <Image Source="/Images/Record.png"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>

            <Button.Style>
                <!-- initially disabled-->
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>

            <!-- fade effect while disabled-->
            <Button.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.OpacityMask>

        </Button>

        <Label Name ="RecordLabel" Content="RECORD" Margin="785,367,112,287" FontSize="20"/>


        <!-- quit button -->
        <Button Name ="Quit" Margin="931,631,10,27" Click="Quit_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Quit.png"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Name ="QuitLabel" Content="QUIT" Margin="940,661,0,0" FontSize="10"/>

        <!-- info button -->
        <Button Name ="Info" Margin="880,631,61,27" Click="Info_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Images/Info.png"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Name ="InfoLabel" Content="INFO" Margin="889,661,61,0" FontSize="10"/>

        <!-- browse button -->
        <Button Name ="Browse" Margin="829,631,112,27" Click="Browse_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Browse.jpg"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Name ="BrowseLabel" Content="BROWSE" Margin="828,661,108,0" FontSize="10"/>

        <!-- save button -->
        <Button Name ="Save" Margin="778,631,163,27" Click="Save_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Save.png"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Name ="SaveLabel" Content="SAVE" Margin="786,661,163,-11" FontSize="10"/>

        <!-- open button -->
        <Button Name ="Open" Margin="727,631,214,27" Click="Open_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Open.png"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Name ="OpenLabel" Content="OPEN" Margin="731,661,211,0" FontSize="10"/>

        <!-- new button -->
        <Button Name ="New" Margin="676,631,265,27" Click="New_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Images/NewProject.jpg"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Name ="NewLabel" Content="NEW" Margin="685,661,257,0" FontSize="10"/>



        <!-- hamburger button -->
        <Button Name ="hamburger" Margin="836,501,10,80" MouseEnter="hamburger_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="bg">
                        <Image Source="/Images/Hamburger.png"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Label Content="MAIN MENU" Margin="836,580,-27,67" FontSize="25"/>

        </Grid>

        <!--************************************************************************* MAIN SCREEN END***************************************************************************************-->



        <!--************************************************************************* IMPORT SCREEN 1st page ***************************************************************************************-->

        <Grid Name="IMPORT_SCREEN_1st_page">

            <Grid.Style>
                <!-- initially hidden-->
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="Hidden" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>

            <!--tree view file selection-->
        <Menu Name ="SelectFileMenu" Margin="310,220,145,287" >

            <!-- file selection box-->
            <ComboBox Width="518" Height="26" />

        </Menu>




        <!-- windows dialog box (temporarily)-->

        <Button Name ="open_file" Margin="140,438,801,220" Click="Open_Win_Dialog">

            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Images/open_temp.jpg"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>


        </Grid>
```

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use MARGIN to make things where they are supposed to be!  Your Margin property in each of your controls is setting an absolute position for your buttons etc.  This obviously won't do when you change the size of the window.  You need relative spacing.

Since you are using `<Grid>`, set some `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` to make controls appear where they are supposed to, and sized accordingly.  See this for starters:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

ie.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="OK" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

This will make 3 rows, the bottom and top rows will proportionally fill your window, and the Auto height of the middle row would size to fit the height of the button.  This would mean the button would be in the middle of the screen, always, no matter the windows size.  This is much better than trying to use Margin="279,345,100,208" or whatever to put the button where you want it, because as soon as the window changes, that Margin will force it to not be in the same spot, relatively.

Comment: +1 for @TheodosiusVonRichthofen, `Margin` is not meant to be used for relative layout. Using `Row/ColumnDefinition` can get really messy at some point though.

Comment: true.  most complex layouts will bend up using a combination of different controls, ie. Grids and DockPanels, StackPanels etc.  Just a quick example for the OP to get him started.  OP will need to read and understand WPF layouts, there are several links provided so far

Comment: I know this is probably easy but I am so confused. The reason why I used the margin is because as I visually drag and position an element in preview window (which I found very easy and convenient), the margin gets set automatically. Can you please apply the code above for one of the elements from my example, just so I get some idea what exactly to do for the rest?

Comment: Try to get away from drag and dropping your interface together. It's convenient for about 5 minutes, then you realise you need to put several hundred controls in several hundred irritatingly specific places and it's a *nightmare*.

Comment: you now find drag and drop NOT convenient.  At all. Just type in your XAML and get used to it, it'll save you time and headache in the long run

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to only use `Margin` in the context of **relative** positioning. Using this will allow your controls to be dynamically positioned when the window changes it's size.

Currently, your margins look like this:

```
Margin="329,438,319,163"
```

This is like saying: *"Put the control here, and keep it there"*.

Whereas, they should be **relative** to the parent control. Instead of a straightforward defined margin.

Something a little more like this:

```
Margin="12"
```

Which would be like saying: *"Set the margin to be 12 on all sides within the parent control, if the parent resizes, then resize this control too"*.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653621/relative-positioning-in-wpf-xaml) and [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFGrid.aspx).

Comment: This is a good start, but the Margin values alone shouldn't be used to position elements in the Window, which is what's happening just now. OP is going to have to make better use of his Grids.