# XAML design in Visual Studio different from actual program display

Tags: c#, xaml, render

I have a desktop application I am building in C# with XAML. I am having troube with the XAML side of things, and how its displayed on the preview compared to the actual program view.

I have tried putting the elements I am using into a grid, a stackPanel but it still has the same issue. Here is what the program should look like:

[image: what it should look like]

And how it actually appears in the program:

[image: And how it actually appears]

```
<Page x:Class="project.PayFees"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mosque"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="Pay Fees">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Margin="67,90,641,328" Content="Amount Paid"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding PayFees}" Content="Pay Fees" Margin="584,405,10,10" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="1.172,-3.328"/>
        <Label Margin="67,62,691,360" Content="Date" RenderTransformOrigin="0.684,-0.03"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="StudentID" Text="{Binding StudentID}" Width="130" 
    Margin="159,126,511,290" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.285,-6.056" />
        <Label Content="Student ID" RenderTransformOrigin="3.77,3.251" Margin="67,126,663,292"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AmountPaid" Text="{Binding AmountPaid}" Width="130" 
    Margin="159,90,511,328" RenderTransformOrigin="0.039,0.004"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Date}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,52,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="2.704,6.1" Width="130" Height="32"/>
        <Button Content="Load Student" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,136,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Height="22" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="studentName" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,165,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is my XAML code.

I can't figure out why this is happening - any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I can't see the pictures in normal size...

Comment: Your problem is in the fixed position of the controls. Look at this answer [Relative positioning in WPF xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653621/relative-positioning-in-wpf-xaml)